# How to delete actionbar's bottom line

Tags: android

I want to let the action bar bottom line disappear , i try to use `toolbar.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);`
Obviously it's not working.

Is it possible to let the bottom line disappear ? any help would be grateful ,thanks.

[image: i want to let the line disappear]

my MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.taiwandigestionsociety_v11.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my toolbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:background="#29395e">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

According some responding i set the MainActivity about action bar like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initViews();

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);//it dosen't work, i use the app theme too.
```

my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#29395e</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<!-- ToolBar-->
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: elevation .....

Comment: Use inside `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout  app:elevation="0dp">`

Comment: yes it is , i had got the solution , thanks @Satan Pandeya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApplication.ActionBar</item>
</style>


<style name="Theme.MyApplication.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<!-- <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item> -->
<!-- if you are using support library thn elevation should be without android namespace like below else the above one uncomment-->
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

To handle below 5.0

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

**Or**

below things not applicable for the pre lollipop

If support action bar

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

If not support actionbar

```
getActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Please let me know if anything.

Comment: thanks @user1140237 , <item name="elevation">0dp</item> is the solution , thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

From Android 5.0 onward you can use `setElevation()` to adjust the elevation,ie what you mentioned as *bottom_line* .

To do so :

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: i got the solution is <item name="elevation">0dp</item> , thanks for your attention @Superman , i thank you on behalf of the earth

Answer (score 1):

For pre-lollipop devices - Add this line into your App theme:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

However this doesn't work on version 5.0 and higher. So you have to call `setElevation(0)` on your action bar. Note that if you're using the support library you must call it to that like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: thanks your help , i try it both , it's not working for me.

Comment: What is `ToolBarStyle`?

Comment: i got the solution is <item name="elevation">0dp</item> , thanks for your attention @Wizard